# retrieve path of a file created ios

Tags: ios, filenames, filepath, nsbundle

I have the following code for creating a file:

```
NSString *name = @"dtmf-received.aif";

//create file
NSString *cachesFolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
fileName= [cachesFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
```

I need to get the path of the created file. The following code is not working. What am I missing?

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dtmf-received.aif"
                                                         ofType:@""];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caches directory and the app bundle directory are different.  Simply use the same code in both places and it will work correctly.

Comment: what do you mean to use the same code? Could you please  add the example?

Comment: The first piece of code is correct so use it everywhere.

Comment: I ve changed with this   NSString* filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] pathForResource:@"dtmf-received.aif" ofType:@"aif"]; and now i have a crash.

Comment: I don't understand why you are finding this so difficult.  That code isn't the same as the first piece of code, is it?  Use the same code.

Comment: so i can use the filePath as fileName. ok , thank you!

Comment: thank you! could u also tell me how could i create an empty file of 10 562 bytes for example in ios? This file will be opened with stream open and with stream write i ll append some data

Comment: @justME You'll need to ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here it is an example how you can play your aif file:


-(void) playSound {
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dtmf-received" ofType:@"aif"];
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
    //[soundPath release];
    NSLog(@"soundpath retain count: %d", [soundPath retainCount]);
}
```

Comment: thank you! could u also tell me how could i create an empty file of 10 562 bytes for example in ios? This file will be opened with stream open and with stream write i ll append some data

Comment: This is the exact size you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        NSString *fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dtmf-received" ofType:@"aif"];
        NSURL *vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileLocation];
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:vedioURL];
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
        [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: thank you! could u also tell me how could i create an empty file of 10 562 bytes for example in ios? This file will be opened with stream open and with stream write i ll append some data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set .aif to 'Type:' string

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dtmf-received.aif"
                                                     ofType:@""];
```

Try this->

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dtmf-received"
                                                     ofType:@"aif"];
```

And check project 'Copy Bundle Resources' section, you file need be here

[image: Copy Bundle Resouces]

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I also need to create the dtmf-received.aif. Could you please help me to create the file in main bundle?

Comment: drag your file to 'Copy Bundle Resources'

Comment: how could i create a file of specific size in ios?